# How to access and use user secrets in a saturn application

Tags: asp.net-core, f#, saturn-framework, safe-stack

**Edit**: here are some adaptions to the answer by Koenig Lear,in case someone else stumbles upon this question:

to add user secrets to the application i used this code, where the ID used by `config.AddUserSecrets` is the secrets id that gets added to the Server.fsproj by using `dotnet user-secrets init`.

```
app
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
        System.Action<Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilderContext,IConfigurationBuilder> ( fun ctx config ->
            config.AddUserSecrets("6de80bdf-2a05-4cf7-a1a8-d08581dfa887") |> ignore
        )
)
|> run
```

The secret can then be consumed in the router via:

```
 forward "/api" (fun next ctx ->

        let settings = ctx.GetService<IConfiguration>()
        let cString = settings.["Some:ConnectionString"]

        webApp cString next ctx

    )
```

**Original Question:**

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to access user secrets, but i cant quite translate the [example provided by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows).

lets say i have Saturn running in a SAFE stack environment (most likely irrelevant in this case). I have a webApp, which takes a connection string and then handles requests using the provided connection string for DB access:

```
let router connectionString = forward "/api" (webApp connectionString)
```

and a user secret that contains the connection string that i initiated using `dotnet user-secrets set` :

```
{
  "Some:ConnectionString": "Data Source=..."
}
```

and an `application` that uses the router:

```
let app = application {
    url ("https://0.0.0.0:" + port.ToString() + "/")
    use_router (router )
}
```

What i am trying to do is somehow extract the user secret and pass it to the router. What i dont seem to grasp is where and how to perform the dependency injection that ASP.NetCore usually does (see where the user secret is configured via the `Configuration API` in the MS Docs example.).

What comes very close to what i am trying to do is [this section from the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows#string-replacement-with-secrets) :

```
public class Startup
{
    private string _connection = null;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("Movies"));
        builder.Password = Configuration["DbPassword"];
        _connection = builder.ConnectionString;
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"DB Connection: {_connection}");
        });
    }
}
```

The first problem is that i cant find how to get the `Configuration` object that contains the `GetConnectionString` method. But even if i could do that, i would configure this section via the `service_config` operation in the `application` monad right? But then I can't use the obtained connection string for the router, because the `use_router` operation is separated from it.

I am using Saturn 0.14.1 on netcoreapp/asp.netcore 3.1 .

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the *ConfigureAppConfiguration* method:

```
open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets

let configureAppConfiguration  (context: WebHostBuilderContext) (config:IConfigurationBuilder) =  
    config
        .AddUserSecrets()

app
   .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configureAppConfiguration)
   .run
```

Inside your router you could use it like this:

```
let webApp = router {
    get "/" (fun next ctx ->
        task {
            let settings = ctx.GetService<IConfiguration>()
            let s = settings.["Some:ConnectionString"]
            ...
        })
}
```

Comment: This is one of the things I initially tried, but `ConfigureAppConfiguration` does not take a function as input, but a System.Action: This expression was expected to have type
    'System.Action<Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilderContext,IConfigurationBuilder>'    
but here has type
    ''a -> 'b -> IConfigurationBuilder'. Additionally to that, this is the way to add secrets right? How would i access them from your example?

Comment: @Mutagene Action is just a function type :) in C# functions are not first-class so they need to create a delegate type: System.Action but in f# that is just Action<'a,'b> = 'a->'b->unit

Comment: I had to adapt your code a bit, but thanks to you i made it work. Thank you very much! ill add my adaptions to the original question in case someone else stumbles upon this.